# UIAnimation works normally but stops working after i exit from the view(it enters background) where it is placed and enter again(enters foreground)

Tags: ios, swift

i am presently running an animation that makes an image move on screen, it works but i noticed that anytime i run the app for the first time, it works normally but when i exit the view and re-enter the view of the animation, it never runs again. i have tried placing the function that runs the animation in different view controller life cycles but no improvement. code is below.

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    moveIt(rootView.eclipseImageView)
    applyGradient()
  }

    func moveIt(_ imageView: UIImageView) {
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let viewWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let fullDayCycle = 24
    let secondsInAnHour = 3600
    let hoursLeftToMoveSun = fullDayCycle - hour
    let totalSecondsLeftToMoveSun = secondsInAnHour * hoursLeftToMoveSun
    let moveSunBy = (Int(viewWidth) * hoursLeftToMoveSun) / 24
    let moveSunByInCGFloat = CGFloat(moveSunBy)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 30, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
      imageView.frame.origin.x =  viewWidth  // moveSunByInCGFloat
      // self.view.backgroundColor =   UIColor(hexaString: "#1f0001")
    }, completion: { [weak self] (_) in
      self?.moveIt(imageView)
    })
  }

    func applyGradient() {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    let hour = 4
    gradient.colors = switchNewColors(hour)
    gradient.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi, 0, 0, 1)
    gradient.shouldRasterize = true
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)  // addSublayer(gradient)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code animates your `imageView` from it's original frame to a frame with `origin.x` at `viewWidth`. Once you've run that animation, your `imageView`'s frame's `origin.x` will be equal to `viewWidth` forever after. Future calls to `moveIt()` won't change anything because you've already changed the imageView's frame.

Further, your animation's completion closure calls `moveIt(_:)` again, which also won't change anything.

What do you want new calls to `moveIt(_:)` to do?

Comment: Actually, i set the imageView's frame's origin.x  to viewWidth for testing purpose, i have removed the  moveIt(_:) in the completion block.